# If Veda Vyasa compiled the Vedas, why does the Atharva Veda mention Parikshit as the compiler of the four Vedas?

Tags: vedas, vyasa, atharva-veda

Veda Vyasa split the Vedas into four and was the compiler of the four Vedas. Why does the Atharva Veda (Hymn 127 of Book 20) mention Parikshit to be the compiler of the Vedas then?

Comment: Can you give the reference. I am not able to find such a thing in the book

Comment: Since it is too long to write here, I am giving you a link to this answer: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/28698/was-the-atharva-veda-compiled-at-the-time-of-king-parikshit

Comment: Also, if the Mahabharata happened before the time of King Parikshit, why do the Vedas not even mention the war itself at any point of time?

Comment: There’s another fun fact. Janamejaya, son of Parikshit has Ashwamedha performed by Shaunaka (the person who listens to the Puranas from Sutaji). He finds mentions in the Shatapatha Brahmana, the Brahmana attached to the Vajasaneyi Samhita (Shukla Yajurveda)

Comment: Very interesting. But, then, why do the Vedas not mention the Mahabharata war anywhere? And, what about the reference to another Parikshit as being the great great great grandfather of Bhishma? Is that an interpolation to account for the genealogical inconsistencies?

Comment: I don’t know. Though indolgists say that the Dasharajna battle of the Rigveda was a story from which people distorted and created the Mahabharata. I know it sounds preposterous, but that’s what indologists say

Comment: I know. Also another thing, Kiron Krishnan on quora claims this is evidence to prove the Mahabharata is fiction (kings before and after it are mentioned but never the Pandavas or the war itself). What is your opinion on this?

Comment: Well, we even have Bhagavan’s Trivikrama leela mentioned in Rigveda. So why could it just not mention Kurukshetra war directly??

Comment: Exactly. Effectively this leaves us with two choices: either the Mahabharata never happened, or it for some reason was not mentioned in the Vedas (the first of which seems to be more likely as the Vedas even mention minor kings, so why wouldn't there be a mention of a large-scale pan-Indian war?) But the confusing part is, if it's fiction, why the Mahabharata and Ramayana mention events in such a detailed form (the latter dedicates two entire sargas just to explain the various astras and shastras and 2/3rds of the Mahabharata is just geography). Add to the vivid descriptions of Lanka's flora.

Comment: We need to first understand what Vedas are actually supposed to be. Then we will understand why or why not something should or should not be mentioned in the Vedas. One thing to however remember in the traditional view is - itihasapuranabhyam vedam samupabrmhayet - the teachings of the Vedas need to be expanded using the Puranas. I.e. Vedas precede the Puranas. Therefore should the Vedas be mentioning any puranic events in the first place?

Comment: What you say is right, but shouldn't the Vedas at least mention such a large scale war or even at least have an indirect reference to it? I mean, the Mahabharata killed billions (probably an exaggeration) of people. Shouldn't such a monumental and important war at least be indirectly referenced in the Vedas? Shouldn't the Pandavas at least get one mention? Hell, the Vedas don't even mention the Pandavas ruling Indraprastha.

Comment: Now what can we do :). I have asked a question on the site for this purpose. It’ll help get better knowledge. Btw in your question ka translation I don’t see it saying Parikshit compiled the Veda’s. The question says- were they Veda’s compiled at his time by Veda Vyasa.

Comment: Fair enough. But according to Wikipedia Parikshit's reign was when the Vedas were first composed. Thank you very much, but I asked a question about it myself (as to why the Mahabharata characters are not mentioned in the Vedas) and got no response. Kiron Krishnan also claims that Arjuna's story was plagiarised from the story of Kutsa in the Vedas (which does not make much sense because aside from being born from Indra, Kutsa being Indra's charioteer and friend and Indra blocking out the sun, Arjuna and Kutsa's stories have absolutely nothing in common)

Comment: Puranic accounts won’t support Veda’s being composed during his reign.

Comment: Well yes. But then again the authenticity of the Puranas is questioned (even I do not fully believe in their authenticity because some Puranas like Skanda Purana have been adulterated to the point where they are no longer recognisable) by many people because the Puranas largely contain contradictions within one another and are sectarian (there are stories defaming Shiva in the Puranas by the Vaishnavite sectarians and vice versa). Some even go as far as to say that the Puranas were inventions to adulterate the principles of the Vedas.

Comment: Fair enough. One could say the same thing about the Samhitas?

Comment: Not exactly. The Samhitas generally refer to the oldest parts of the Vedas (which leave very little room for interpolation because of how the Vedas were transmitted) while the Puranas at times contradict in the same book.

Comment: Another thing. In the Atharva Veda it is said that:- “In this way, all the Vedas were manifested along with the Kalpas, Rahasyas, Brahmanas, Upanisads, Itihasas, Anvakhyatas and the Puranas.”
Atharva Veda: Gopatha Brahmana, purva 2.10

Do the Puranas and Itihasas refer to the Mahabharata and the Ramayana, and the Puranas as we have them today?

Answer (score 1):

First, any translation by Ralph T. Griffiths is highly suspect. He is a known Western Christian Orientalist of the 19th century and his knowledge of Sanskrit was limited. People keeping on referring to his various translations as they are the one most widely published on the internet - because they were available and free. He is not recognized as a Sanskrit scholar within India.

Some Puranas refer to Vyasa (the author of the Mahabharata) as the compiler of the vedas; and the vedas as generally organized, or compiled, by Vyasa are recognized by all modern day Hindus (followers of the Uttara Mimamsa, no matter what sect or school).

It should be remembered that the vedas are the revealed word of God, there is no human authorship. The Brahma Sutras 1.3.29-30 says: (https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/brahma-sutras/d/doc62930.html)

> Sutra 1,3.29
>
> अत एव च नित्यत्वम् ॥ २९ ॥
>
> ata eva ca nityatvam || 29 ||
>
> ata-eva—From this very reason; ca—also; nityatvam—the eternity.
>
> 29. From this very reason also (results) the eternity (of the Vedas).
>
> Since the objects are eternal, that is, gods etc. as types are eternal, the Vedic words are eternal. This establishes the eternal nature of the Vedas. The Vedas were not written by anybody. They are impersonal and eternal. The Rishis only discovered them but were not authors of the Vedic texts.
>
> “By means of their past good deeds (the priests) attained the capacity to understand the Vedas; (then) they found them dwelling in the Rishis” (Rig-Veda 10.71.3), which shows that the Vedas are eternal.
>
> Brahma-Sutra 1.3.30: Sanskrit text and English translation.
>
> समाननामरूपत्वाच्चावृत्तावप्यविरोधो दर्शनात् स्मृतेश्च ॥ ३० ॥
>
> samānanāmarūpatvāccāvṛttāvapyavirodho darśanāt smṛteśca || 30 ||
>
> samāna-nāmarūpatvāt—Because of similar names and forms; ca—and; āvṛttau—in the revolving of the world cycles; api—even; avirodhaḥ—no contradiction; darśanāt—from the Sruti; smṛteḥ—from the Smriti; ca—and.
>
> 30. And because of the sameness of names anid forms (in every fresh cycle) there is no contradiction (to the eternity of the Vedic words) even in the revolving of the world cycles, as is seen from the Sruti and the Smriti.
>
> An objection is raised. Since at the end of a cycle everything is completely destroyed and creation begins afresh at the beginning of the next cycle, there is a break in the continuity of existence; so even as types the gods are not eternal. This upsets the eternal relation of Vedic words and the objects they represent, and consequently the eternity of the Vedas and their authority fall to the ground. This Sutra refutes it. Just as a person after waking from deep sleep finds no break in the continuity of existence, so also in the state of Pralaya (end of a cycle) the world is in a potential state—in seed form—in ignorance, and not completely destroyed; at the beginning of the next cycle it is again manifested into a gross form with all the previous variety of names and forms. As the world does nqt become absolutely non-existent, the eternity of the relation between Vedic words and their objects is not contradicted, and consequently the authoritativeness of the Vedas remains. This eternal existence of the world in gross and fine forms alternatively and the similarity of the names and forms are brought out by the Sruti and Smriti texts. “As formerly the Lord ordered the sun and the moon, heaven,, earth, the sky” etc. (Rig-Veda 10 . 190. 3).

And in the Brhadaranyaka Upanisad II.iv.10 (https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-brihadaranyaka-upanishad/d/doc117950.html) it says:

> Verse 2.4.10:
>
> स यथार्द्रएधाग्नेरभ्याहितात्पृथग्धूमा विनिश्चरन्ति, एवं वा अरेऽस्य महतो भूतस्य निह्̣स्वसितमेतद्यदृग्वेदो यजुर्वेदह्̣ सामवेदोऽथर्वाङ्गिरस इतिहासह्̣ पुराणम् विद्या उपनिस्̣अदह्̣ श्लोकाह्̣ सूत्रान्यनुव्याख्यानानि व्याख्यानानि; अस्यैवैतानि निःश्वसितानि ॥ १० ॥
>
> sa yathārdraedhāgnerabhyāhitātpṛthagdhūmā viniścaranti, evaṃ vā are'sya mahato bhūtasya niḥsvasitametadyadṛgvedo yajurvedaḥ sāmavedo'tharvāṅgirasa itihāsaḥ purāṇam vidyā upaniṣadaḥ ślokāḥ sūtrānyanuvyākhyānāni vyākhyānāni; asyaivaitāni niḥśvasitāni || 10 ||
>
> 10. As from a fire kindled with wet faggot diverse kinds of smoke issue, even so, my dear, the Ṛg-Veda, Yajur-Veda, Sāma-Veda, Atharvāṅgirasa, history, mythology, arts, Upaniṣads, verses, aphorisms, elucidations and explanations are (like) the breath of this infinite Reality. They are like the breath of this (Supreme Self).
>
> Likewise it may be understood that the universe, at the time of its origin as also prior to it, is nothing but Brahman. As before the separation of the sparks, smoke, embers and flames, all these are nothing but fire, and therefore there is but one substance, fire, so it is reasonable to infer that this universe differentiated into names and forms is, before its origin, nothing but Pure Intelligence. This is expressed as follows: As from a fire kindled with wet faggot diverse kinds of smoke issue. The word ‘smoke’ is suggestive of sparks etc. as well—meaning smoke, sparks, etc., issue. Like this example, O Maitreyī, all this is like the breath of this infinite Reality, the Supreme Self that is being discussed. ‘Breath’ here means, like the breath. As a man breathes without the slightest effort, so do all these come out of It. What are those things that are spoken of as issuing from It as Its breath? The Ṛg-Veda, Yajur-Veda, Sāma-Veda, Atharvāṅgirasa, i.e. the four kinds of Mantras. History, such as the dialogue between Urvaśī and Purūravas—‘The nymph Urvaśī,’ and so on (Ś. XI. iv. 4. 1); it is this Brāhmaṇa that is meant. Mythology, such as, ‘This universe was in the beginning unmanifest,’ etc. (Tai. II. 7). Arts, which treat of music, dancing, etc.—‘This is also Veda,’ etc. (Ś. XIII. iv. 3. 10-14). Upaniṣads, such as, ‘It should be meditated upon as. dear,’ etc. (IV. 1. 3). Verses, the Mantras occurring in the Brāhmaṇas, such as, ‘Regarding this there are the following verses’ (IV. iii. 11; IV. iv. 8). Aphorisms, those passages of the Vedas which present the truth in a nutshell, for example,. ‘The Self alone is to be meditated upon’ (I. iv. 7). Elucidations —of the Mantras. Explanations, eulogistic passages. Or ‘elucidations’ may be of the ‘aphorisms’ above. As the passage, ‘The Self alone is to be meditated upon, or the passage, ‘He (who worships another god thinking), “He is one, and I am another,” does not know. He is like an animal (to the gods)’ (I. iv. 1o), has this concluding portion of the present chapter as its elucidation. And ‘explanations’ may be of the Mantras. Thus these are the eight divisions of the Brāhmaṇas.
>
> So only the Mantras and Brāhmaṇas are meant.[5] It is the eternally composed and already existent Vedas that are manifested like a man’s breath—without any thought or effort on his part. Hence they are an authority as regards their meaning, independently of any other means of knowledge. Therefore those who aspire after well-being must accept the verdict of the Vedas on knowledge or on rites, as it is. The differentiation of forms invariably depends on the manifestation of their names.[6] Name and form are the limiting adjuncts of the Supreme Self, of which, when they are differentiated, it is impossible to tell whether they are identical with or different from It, as is the case with the foam of water. It is name and form in all their stages[7] that constitute relative existence. Hence name has been compared to breath. By this statement it is implied that form too is like breath. Or we may explain it differently: In the passage, ‘The Brāhmaṇa ousts one.... all this is the Self’ (II. iv. 6; IV. v. 7), the entire world of duality has been spoken of as the domain of ignorance. This may lead to a doubt about the authority of the Vedas. In order to remove this doubt it is said that since the Vedas issue without any effort like a man’s breath, they are an authority; they are not like other books.

To ask from a Western historical 'fact' methodology as to 'who' compiled the vedas is something that will lie eternally unanswered in the sands of time, and eternally subject to speculation and opinion. From a Hindu assertion, however, the vedas are the eternal Word of God revealed by God Himself.